# Android textview, breaks text containing a character into several lines

Tags: android, textview

I use a special font for a TextView to show phonetic symbols in an Android application. But the TextView is broken into several lines if the text contains `ə` character:

[image]

`ə` in the font is the same as the letter `e`.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

I tested it on two phones and both have the same problem.

---

The TextView in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#F5FDFB"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_page3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textview_pronunciation"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="kri`dVetI"
                    android:textColor="#368DEB"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The font is added to the resources and I change the font programmatically using `getFont` and `setTypeface` methods.

The font:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the layout.xml? Also, are you setting the text on the layout or programmaticly?

Comment: @javdromero I'll edit to add it.

Comment: Which font are you using? Also, the whole .xml would be better because other items maybe pushing the TextView content since you have wrap_content

Comment: @javdromero I added a full page xml. and how the font looks like..

Answer (score 0):

This function fixes the problem in Xamarin:

```
    static SpannableString FixPhoneticFont(string phonetic)
    {
        SpannableString ret = new SpannableString(phonetic);
        for (int i = 0; i < phonetic.Length; i++)
            ret.SetSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f), i, i + 1, 0);
        return ret;
    }
```